# Center div inside a div vertically

Tags: html, css

I have tried all methods i could find .. and nothing worked for me...
i just can wrap my head around what is the problem of aligning a div (or a block element) inside another div .. what could be so difficult..

I want to align the green block vertically.

here is the fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/795St/1/

```
<div class="rtl centerwrapper">
    <div class="green-block pull-right"></div>
    <div class="green-block pull-right"></div>
    <div class="green-block pull-right"></div>
    <div>Average</div>
</div>

.green-block {
    background-color: #02A556;
    margin: 0 .25em 0 .25em !important;
    width: 1em;
    height: 0.5em;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
.rtl {
    direction:rtl;
}
.centerwrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Please .. can any one help .. and explain what am i dooing wrong ?

Edit:
Let me be more clear...
I need all element in one line.
just the blocks needs to be aligned at the vertical middle of the text.

Edit2: here is an image

[image]

Comment: I think it is better you add an image in your question for what output do you need.

Comment: I don't know if you want to keep the height of the green blocks, but if you add a padding: 5px; to the green blocks, at least it looks prettier, although it's not a good solution

Comment: @Mortalus Check the edited answer, screenshot is attached in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Answer**

Here is the new fiddle link http://fiddle.jshell.net/795St/16/

**CSS**

```
.green-block {
    background-color: #02A556;
    margin: 0 .25em 0 .25em !important;
    width: 1em;
    height: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;    
}
.pull-right {
    display: inline-table;
}
.rtl {
    direction:rtl;
}
.centerwrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
}

HTML
<div class="rtl centerwrapper">

    <div class="green-block pull-right"></div>
    <div class="green-block pull-right"></div>
    <div class="green-block pull-right"></div>
    <div class="pull-right">Average</div>
</div>
```

*Screenshot of output*

[image: Center aligned divs]

**Old Answer**

Here is the required output
http://fiddle.jshell.net/795St/5/

```
.pull-right {
    display: inline-table;
}

.centerwrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    text-align: center;
}
```

For inner divs I added `display` as `inline-table` so that they will not be treated as block element and shown in one line. For the outer div I added `text-align` as `center`. SO that it will show the contents in center.

Only 2 changes done to your fiddle.

1. For inner `div` instead of `float: right` I added `display:inline-table`
2. And for outer `div` added `text-align:center`.

Comment: absolute positionning is not needed if you follow display:table/inline-table , use it too on body. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605750/center-div-inside-a-div-vertically#answer-22606304

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/795St/15/)

Is it ok ?

```
.centerwrapper div:last-child{
    margin-top:-8px;
 }
```

Comment: I don't know if you want to keep the height of the green blocks, but if you add a padding: 5px; to the green blocks, at least it looks prettier, although it's not a good solution

Comment: changed margin thats for identify the margin space , thats not a problem i think @Farewyth

Comment: Oh wow, i ment to post this comment to the question  itself, sorry about that.

Comment: but everything is stacked now .. i want it in one line .. see the updated question with the image...

Comment: Edited my answer , is it ok   @Mortalus

Answer (score 0):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/n234A/

Give your green block an appropriate top margin to make them sit in the middle of the wrapper.

In this demo I gave the wrapper div a red background to show centering better

Answer (score 0):

you can use **display:flex** to do this : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wmECy

```
html,body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
}
body , body > div{
  display:flex;
}
div {

  margin:auto;
}
.green-block {
    background-color: #02A556;
    margin: 0 .25em 0 .25em !important;
    width: 1em;
    height: 0.5em;
order:4;
}
.first {
  flex:1;
    order:1;
}
```

or **display:table** http://jsfiddle.net/MxE8Y/5/ (includes IE8)

```
body, html {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:table;
}
body {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
div {
    display:table;
    direction:rtl;
    margin:auto;
    border-spacing:0.25em;
}
.green-block {
    background-color: #02A556;
    width: 1em;
    height: 0.5em;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .green-block {
   background-color: #02A556;
   margin: 6px 10px!important;
   width: 1em;
   height: 0.5em;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You must display all divs as `inline-block`s

`.centerwrapper div {
    display: inline-block;
}`

Answer (score -1):

HTML Code 
    
        
            
            
            
         
        
        Average

and CSS

```
.green-block {
            background-color: #02A556;
            margin: 0 .25em 0 .25em !important;
            width: 1em;
            height: 0.5em;
            margin:10px!important;
            list-style:none;
        }
        .pull-right {
            float: right;
        }
        .rtl {
            direction:rtl;
        }
        .centerwrapper {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: visible;
        }
        .clear{
            clear:both;
        }
```

use this.and give margin at what size you want

Comment: This is not acceptable as im looking for a general solution for all block elements to be centered